# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed laravel 7

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

*parcel table*

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id');
$table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops');
```

** I have a model name Shop I want to add its is to id as a foreign key to parcel table **

Comment: `shops` table need to migrate **before** the `parcels` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem lies in the order you created your migrations. Look at the order and make sure that **shops** table comes before the **parcels** table. If this is not the case, then the easiest way would be to change the table times **e.g.** date_time_name. Change time and you'll be set.

Comment: Ah that's great mate. Now go build awesome things. Cheers.